# ASM jbe not working (fpu)

Tags: assembly

I want to compare a float on the stack (st(0)) and value in variable temp.
Why jae works good (jumps to @Next), but jbe not jumping to @Next2?

```
mov     te, 254
fild    te;
mov     rax, 0;
mov     temp, 0
fcom    temp;
fstsw   ax;
SAHF;
jae @Next
mov byte ptr [rcx], 0;
ret;

@Next:
mov     rax, 0
mov     temp, 255
fcom    temp;
fstsw   ax;
SAHF;
jbe     @Next2
mov byte ptr [rcx], 255
ret;

@Next2:
fistp   word ptr [rcx];
```

Comment: Since your branches rely only on the carry flag, why not replace `fcom` + `fstsw` + `sahf` with `fcomi` ?

Comment: @Michael will it be faster (I need to push on stack, fcomi and pop)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mov     temp, 255
fcom    temp;
```

This will not work because `fcom` expects a floating-point operand, and you're providing it with an integer operand. For the value 0 this happens to work, because `0x00000000` and `0.0` have the same bit pattern.

One way of solving this would be to change `fcom` to `ficom`:

```
ficom word ptr [temp]  ; or dword ptr, depending on the size of temp
```